# Rounded imageview not working

Tags: android, xml, imageview, rounding, ontouchlistener

I am creating a drums app. Everything works fine. But the drums images are not rounded. I mean they look circle but when touched around, the whole square area around it is responding.

I am using `imageviews` in layout for the drum images. And **ontouchlistener** on that `imageviews`.

For ex

[image]

Ignore the black part..Consider my drum is just the red part in the image. White part is not visible, but when finger is touched on the white part, it responds.

I tried adding rounded background as said in some forums.

**roundbutton.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#eeffffff" />
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"  
    android:topRightRadius="8dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dip"/>
</shape>
```

added this to imageviews but still not working. PLease help me.

Comment: why dont you use photoshop to neatly crop the picture as a circle, make it .png then use it in your app?!

Comment: yeah i did that. i have a perfect circle. but not working.

Comment: Buttons are always square, even if the image displayed is not. You will manually have to check if the TouchEvent is outside the radius of the circle and discard it in that case.

Comment: So i need to use touchevents instead of touchlistener......?

Comment: can you elaborate on your idea please.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the roundbutton.xml to a **selector** and specify an item with **android:state_pressed="true"**. This item will be shown when you click on the view

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#eeffffff"/>
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        </shape>        
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#eeffff00"/>
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: you did not understand my problem..I dont want a selector..i want to only touch the circle..not the square around it.

Comment: That is diffilut to implement. You have to override the onTouchListner and calcuate whether the touch is inside or outside the radius of the imageview